# $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $(x-2)f(x)-(x+1)f(x-1) = 3$. Evaluate $f(2013)$, given that $f(2)=5$

Tags: functions, induction

The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $(x-2)f(x)-(x+1)f(x-1) = 3$. Evaluate $f(2013)$, given that $f(2) = 5$.

Comment: What math contest is this from?

Comment: @Potato: [KöMaL](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=honap&h=201304&t=mat&l=en), Problem B. 4538.

Comment: Another example of a question that should have been closed before anybody answered it!

Answer (score 12):

Hint 1: $3=(x+1)-(x-2)$

> $(x-2)f(x)-(x+1)f(x-1)=3\Leftrightarrow (x-2)f(x)-(x+1)f(x-1)=(x+1)-(x-2)\Leftrightarrow (x-2)(f(x)+1)-(x+1)(f(x-1)+1)=0$

---

Hint 2: Is there a function closely related to $f$ that would verify a simpler equation?

> $g(x)=f(x)+1$

$ $

> $(x-2)g(x) - (x+1)g(x-1)=0 \Leftrightarrow (x-2)g(x)=(x+1)g(x-1) \Leftrightarrow g(x)=\cfrac{x+1}{x-2}g(x-1)$

---

> $g(x)=\cfrac{x+1}{x-2}g(x-1)=\cfrac{x+1}{x-2}\cfrac{x+1-1}{x-2-1}g(x-1-1) = \left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \cfrac{x+1-k}{x-2-k}\right) g(x-n)$

Now give the good value to $n$, simplify the product and you'll have the expression of $g$ you need.

Comment: Yeah right. Some terms cancel each other >_<

Comment: What is "the good value"?

Comment: The value sot hat you can evaluate $g(x-n)$

Comment: Big fan of answers with this format +1

Comment: Same here, format+1.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x-1=y$, then,
$$(y-1)f(y+1)-(y+2)f(y)=3$$
$$\implies f(y+1)=\frac{3+(y+2)f(y)}{y-1} \;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

Lemma: $\forall \; n \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n)=n(n-1)(n+1)-1$.

Base Case: If $n=2$ then $f(n)=1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 -1=5$ which is true by information provided in the question.

Inductive Step: Assume for $n=k$ that $f(k)=k(k-1)(k+1)-1$.

Then by equation $(1)$, $$f(k+1)=\frac{3+(k+2)(k(k-1)(k+1)-1)}{k-1}$$
$$=\frac{k^4+2k^3-k^2-3k+1}{k-1}$$
$$=\frac{(k-1)(k^3+3k^2+2k-1)}{k-1}$$
$$=k^3+3k^2+2k-1$$
$$=k(k^2+3k+2)-1$$
$$=k(k+1)(k+2)-1$$

Thus completing the induction.

Hence our Lemma is true and $f(n)=n(n-1)(n+1)-1 \; \forall \; n \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$

In particular, if $n=2013$, $f(2013)=2013 \cdot 2012 \cdot 2014-1=8157014183$ (I confess I used a calculator).

P.S I found the lemma by trying small cases.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions allow you to calculate $f(x+1)$ if you know $f(x)$.  Try calculating $f(3), f(4), f(5), f(6)$, and looking for a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following Mathematica program:

```
f = DifferenceRoot[Function[{f, x}, {(x - 2) f[x] - (x + 1) f[x - 1] == 3, f[2] == 5}]];
f[2013]
```

We get the answer = 8157014183.